# Why does NetBeans keep starting a new emulator?

Tags: netbeans, android-emulator

More often than not, when I hit "Run" NetBeans keeps starting a new emulator yet never runs the application. Yes, I do wait several minutes because I know it can take awhile. This can happen if I start the emulator through the "Tools | Android SDK and AVD Manager" menu bar item. Eventually, things will start working properly (of course I have no idea what I did if anything to make it work). Sometimes I get the dialog that asks to select a running AVD or device or to start the AVD but often I don't get that dialog.

Anybody know what's going on here?

Thanks a bunch, 
Bill